# Surely there must be a way to access 10k tools besides the privileges FAQ?

Tags: support, privileges, 10k-tools

Maybe I'm just blind but the only link I've seen to the 10k tools is from the privileges FAQ:  https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools

Is there some other, more UI-based way to get at them or should I just bookmark that link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They've been buried under the Review tab since its introduction.

If you click on Review, you'll notice at the top of the page, there's a pair of links to toggle between Review and 10K Tools.

[image: Review/Tools]

Alternately, you can just type/bookmark https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tools -  it isn't a particularly complex URL, so you could even memorize it.

Comment: Oh neat.  Thanks.  I've only been 10k for a couple days and I'm still trying to get a handle on where everything is.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't see it mentioned in the [other answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7777/242480), so I figure I would also mention that the Review Queues dropdown also has a "tools" link that'll take you to the 10k tools.

Here's a screenshot with the related link circled ([freehand and in red](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/622284), of course):

[image: Link to the 10k tools in the review queues dropdown panel]